# How to iterate through a folder with multiple excel workbooks containing multiple worksheets create a single data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

The following function is what I have come up with to iterate through multiple excel files to store the data into a single data frame. However, only the data from the final file is being stored in the final data frame. What should I do to get the data from all the files to be stored in the same df and then exported to a csv file ?

```
def excel_to_df(folder, start_row, end_row, start_col, end_col):
    # loop through all excel files in the folder
    for file in os.listdir(folder):
        exact_file_path = folder +  "\\\\" + file 
        print(exact_file_path)
        # check if file is an excel file
        if file.endswith('xlsx'):
            # create workbook and its worksheets for each file
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(exact_file_path)
            ws = wb.worksheets

        # create a list to store the dataframes
        df_list = []

        # iterate over the worksheets
        for worksheet in ws:
            # get the name of the worksheet
            name = worksheet.title
            # create an empty list to store the values
            cell_values = []

            # iterate over the rows and columns in the range

            for row in worksheet.iter_rows(min_row = row_min, max_row = row_max,
                                            min_col = col_min, max_col = col_max):


                                            # append the cell values to the list
                                            cell_values.append([cell.value for cell in row])

                                            # create a dataframe from the cell values and the worksheet name
                                            df = pd.DataFrame(cell_values, columns=range(start_col, end_col+1), index=[name]*len(cell_values))

                                            # append the df to the list
                                            df_list.append(df)


                                            # concatenate the list of dataframes into a single dataframe
                                            df = pd.concat(df_list)
                                            # save the output to a csv file
                                            df.to_csv('test.csv', index=True)

                                            return df
```

Comment: Why bother with a dataframe at all? Looping over `ws.values` will let you write directly to a CSV.

Comment: @CharlieClark I'd guess writing the CSVs is more of a log rather than the final product.  I think they want, as they said, all of the excel files in a single df.

Comment: Dean, why make assumptions? Even so XLSX -> CSV -> DF makes more sense because of the optimisations it allows.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you're creating `df_list` inside the loop so that each time the loop starts over, it will overwrite whatever was already in it.  Additionally, your `return` is at the end of (and inside) the loop so it doesn't ever get to the second element.  When it gets to the `return` it gives you what it has and stops running.  You just need to rearrange it, like this:

```
def excel_to_df(folder, start_row, end_row, start_col, end_col):
    
    # create a list to store the dataframes
    df_list = []
    # loop through all excel files in the folder
    for file in os.listdir(folder):
        exact_file_path = folder +  "\\\\" + file 
        print(exact_file_path)
        # check if file is an excel file
        if file.endswith('xlsx'):
            # create workbook and its worksheets for each file
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(exact_file_path)
            ws = wb.worksheets
        else:
            # if the file doesn't end with xlsx then don't try to open it as though it is
            next
        # iterate over the worksheets
        for worksheet in ws:
            # get the name of the worksheet
            name = worksheet.title
            # create an empty list to store the values
            cell_values = []

            # iterate over the rows and columns in the range

            for row in worksheet.iter_rows(min_row = row_min, max_row = row_max,
                                            min_col = col_min, max_col = col_max):


                                            # append the cell values to the list
                                            cell_values.append([cell.value for cell in row])

            # create a dataframe from the cell values and the worksheet name
            df = pd.DataFrame(cell_values, columns=range(start_col, end_col+1), index=[name]*len(cell_values))

            # append the df to the list
            df_list.append(df)


    # concatenate the list of dataframes into a single dataframe
    df = pd.concat(df_list)
    # save the output to a csv file
    df.to_csv('test.csv', index=True)

    return df
```

As an aside, is there a reason you're manually creating a DF instead of just using `pd.read_excel`?  If not, I'd recommend getting rid of your `for row` loop and just use `pd.read_excel(exact_file_path, sheet_name=worksheet.title)`

Comment: I was creating these data frames because I am extracting only a small part of larger excel files where the data has some rather lengthy text in some of the cells and I did not know that it could be realised with read_excel, but I will try. And thank you for pointing out the mistake in the function.